# access array item using variable

Tags: jquery, arrays

I need to setup a variable and use it to get an item from an array

```
var teamAbbr = "PHI";
var getItemArray = nflLiveStatsTeam.teamAbbr;
console.log(getItemArray); // log is unidentified
```

Using variable above gives me unidentified, but when i console.log below its fine

```
nflLiveStatsTeam.PHI  // log give me the PHI array
```

I get the nflLiveStatsTeam.PHI array items

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the variable in brackets, and the value of the variable will be used instead of the name of the variable itself.

```js
let nflLiveStatsTeam = {
 "PHI" : [
  "test",3,4,5
 ]
};
var teamAbbr = "PHI";
var getItemArray = nflLiveStatsTeam[teamAbbr];
console.log(getItemArray);
```

Comment: swore i tried that first lol , i think my console log was wrong , working not , thanks